# Use folium Map as holoviews DynamicMap

Tags: folium, holoviews, geoviews

I have a `folium.Map` that contains custom HTML Popups with clickable URLs. These Popups open when clicking on the polygons of the map. This is a feature that doesn't seem to be possible to achieve using `holoviews`.

My ideal example of the final application that I want to build with holoviews/geoviews is [here](https://bokeh.oggm.org/explorer/app) with the source code [here](https://github.com/OGGM/world-glacier-explorer/blob/master/app.ipynb), but I would like to exchange the main map with my folium Map and plot polygons instead of rasterized points. Now when I would like to create the `holoviews.DynamicMap` from the folium.Map, holoviews complains (of course) that the data type "map" is not accepted.  Is this somehow still possible?
I have found some [notebook](https://github.com/sfsheath/holoviews-in-folium/blob/master/holoviews-in-folium.ipynb) on GitHub where a holoviews plot in embedded in a folium map using a workaround that writes and reads again HTML, but it seems impossible to embed a folium map into holoviews such that other plots can be updated from this figure using Streams!?

Here is some toy data (from [here](https://panel.holoviz.org/gallery/external/Folium.html)) for the datasets that I use. For simplicity, let's assume I just had point data instead of polygons:

```
import folium as fn
def make_map():
    m = fm.Map(location=[20.59,78.96], zoom_start=5)
    green_p1 = fm.map.FeatureGroup()
    green_p1.add_child(
            fm.CircleMarker(
                [row.Latitude, row.Longitude],
                radius=10, 
                fill=True,
                fill_color=fill_color,
                fill_opacity=0.7
            )
        )
    map.add_child(green_p1)
    return map
```

If I understand it correctly, this needs to be tweaked now in the fashion that it can passed as the first argument to a holoviews.DynamicMap:

```
hv.DynamicMap(make_map, streams=my_streams)
```

where `my_streams` are some other plots that should be updated with the extent of the folium map.
Is that somehow possible or is my strategy wrong?

Comment: You can use a hv.Div object to work with "foreign" plots in holoviews, but I doubt you'll be able to achieve the level of interactivity you're after in any reasonable way. Your other [proposed approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384421/make-bokehs-custom-taptool-work-for-holoviews) seems much more feasible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint in which direction to go! I became a bit desoriented, since I was already very far in folium, and saw many opportunities in holoviews. I'll try and look into the `TapTool`  approach then - maybe I can even try integrate integrate the HTML for my Popup into a Div - that would be a dream ;-)