# Make bokeh's custom TapTool work for holoviews

Tags: bokeh, holoviews, geoviews

I would like to use bokeh's `TapTool` to open a different URL when clicking on each of some `holoviews.Polygons`. An perfect example of how this works in bokeh is in the [bokeh docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#openurl) for point data. However, when I try to use it in holoviews, it doesn't seem to work.
The closest thing I could get to work is this:

```
import geoviews as gv
from bokeh.models import OpenURL, TapTool


url = 'https://google.@domain'
taptool = TapTool()
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)
p = gv.Polygons(data, vdims=['Area', 'domain'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree).options(alpha=1, tools=['hover', taptool])
p
```

The plot shows up nicely, and also the triggering of the URL opening works fine, however the parsing of the "@domain" doesn't work and the URL is "google.???"
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure; seems to work when I do it for this nonsensical example:

```py
import holoviews as hv, numpy as np
hv.extension("bokeh")

def rectangle(x=0, y=0, width=.05, height=.05):
    return np.array([(x,y), (x+width, y), (x+width, y+height), (x, y+height)])

polys = hv.Polygons([{('x', 'y'): rectangle(x, y), 'level': z}
                     for x, y, z in np.random.rand(100, 3)], vdims='level')

url = 'https://google.@level'
taptool = TapTool()
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)
polys.opts(color='level', line_width=1, tools=['hover', taptool])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the bokeh `figure` in holoviews using the `hook` option, described [in the HoloViews docs here](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plots_and_Renderers.html#saving-and-rendering).

With access to the bokeh figure, you can then do things like wire up arbitrary callbacks.
For example, access cursor coords in a python callback, or handle [Tap](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html#bokeh.events.Tap) events:

```py
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.events import MouseMove, Tap

def hook(plot, element):
  # allows access to the bokeh `figure` object
  # so we can bind figure interaction events
  plot.state.on_event(MouseMove, on_mouse_move)
  plot.state.on_event(Tap, on_click)   

  # The handles contain common plot objects
  # plot.handles

def on_mouse_move(event):
  # do something

def on_click(event):
   # do something

my_hv_plot = hv.Points([])
my_hv_plot.opts(hooks=[hook])
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the insight and the nice ready-to-copy example ! :-)